# VBA: If filename.dat in folder contains X, open, run macro, save as filename.xlsm, close

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will search a folder for a .dat file that contains "OPS"(not case sensitive) in the name, if it finds a file I would like to open it and run another macro, save the file as the original filename.xlsm, and close.

So far, I am able to search for the name but that's about the extent of my knowledge.

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lr As Long, fPath As String, fName As String, rFile() As Variant
    fPath = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test\"

    ctr = 1

    fName = dir(fPath & "*.dat")
    Do Until fName = ""

        If InStr(fName, "OPS") > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve rFile(1 To ctr)
            rFile(ctr) = fName
            ctr = ctr + 1
        End If

        fName = dir
    Loop
    For i = LBound(rFile) To UBound(rFile)
        'The variable rFile(i) represents the workbooks you want to work with.
        MsgBox rFile(i)  
    Next
End Sub
```

Ideally, this macro would run any time a .dat file containing OPS in the filename is opened. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To the top add

```
Dim wb as workbook
```

and then replace your message box line with

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & rFile(i))
wb.SaveAs fPath & Split(rFile(i), ".")(0), xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
wb.Close
```

I tested with a tab deliminated file and it worked well.  Your issues may vary if you have a different format.

Comment: Thanks! Its saves to "My Documents" though, is there anyway to save it back to the original folder?